# codemirror in summernote: how to change only color of the font in the code view

Tags: codemirror, summernote

I have enabled codemirror in summernote editor for code view and it works, but I have an issue with font color. Because I am using light color scheme for summernote and dark color scheme for codemirror color of text in codemirror is black (obviously from that light scheme summernote has). I would like somehow to override that and make that text white in codemirror. But how can I do it?

I have noticed that color comes from .note-frame * {...}, so I need somehow to change that.

Greets,
Dejan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution today.
And because it was not possible to override .note-frame * {...} color I decided to remove it. By removing this summernote is receiving main color of the page and that is perfectly fine, I mean why not? In 99% of cases we want the same color of the font on the entire page.